# Is there Any difference between dynamic programming vs branch-bound vs delayed column generation

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, algorithm-design, branch-and-bound

I was reading about cutting stock problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem , this is best solved using dynamic programming but wiki page mentions 2 other techniques names Branch-Bound and delayed column generation...
I read them but it all look same ...every case we break problem into sub problem

Can anyone shed some more light with some example.?

Comment: Wikipedia cites some references with more details.  Did you read those?  If not, that should be your next step.

Comment: DO you undestand what dynamic programming and branch & bound are, respectively?

Comment: Yes I know about Dynamic programming and Branch and Bound. My main doubt was regarding delayed column generation , when can we use that over DP and BB while solving algroithms?

Answer (score -1):

- Dynamic programming is a strategy which avoids explicit enumeration of all possible solutions in the cutting stock problem.
- Branch and bound  is a search based technique also based on pruning. However in branch and bound you might in the worst case need to search over all possible solutions.
- Column generation is a variant of branch and bound where instead of creating all variables at once they are generated sequentially based on which ones are more "attractive".

In terms of implementation you can implement dynamic programming in any general purpose programming language like C or Java while for column generation  you will need to use specialised linear programming solvers as also for Linear programming based branch and bound.

Comment: "Dynamic programming is a divide and conquer strategy" -- that's a dangerous and misleading thing to say. "while for the other two approaches you will need to use specialised integer programming solvers." -- that's plain wrong. Branch-and-bound can be implemented in any language.

Comment: Well I was talking about the special case of branch and bound where the linear relaxation is used for the bounding. Have modified the answer since the "divide and conquer" part did seem subjective.